# Java JOptionPane stepping through Array

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I know the solution is using a for loop to step through the array and display in a pane.  However I am not finding an straight forward explanations on this.  I need a next and a previous button that displays each array element, and just returns to the first element once it reaches the end when the next button is pressed.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < initem.length; i++ ){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, initem[i]);
}
```

initem is the name of my array.

Incorporated ActionListerner

```
class RecordViewer extends JDialog
{
private JButton next;
private JButton prev;
private JLabel label = new JLabel();
private int current = 0;
private CDinventoryItem [] items;



 public RecordViewer(CDinventoryItem [] array){

super();
items = array;

label = this.setLabel(items[Current()]);
next = new JButton("Next");
next.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if( getCurrent() == items.length ){
                setCurrent(0);
        }else{
                setCurrent(getCurrent() + 1);
        }
            setTitle("Inventory Item");
            setSize(1200, 300);
            setLocation(200,200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getLabel().setText(items[getCurrent()].toString());
    }
});

prev = new JButton("Previous");
prev.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if( getCurrent() == 0){
                setCurrent(items.length - 1);
        }else{
                setCurrent(getCurrent() - 1);
        }
            setTitle("Inventory Item");
            setSize(1200, 300);
            setLocation(200,200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getLabel().setText(items[getCurrent()].toString());
    }
});

setLayout(new FlowLayout());
add(label);
add(next);
add(prev);
pack();

this.setVisible(true);
}

public JButton getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(JButton next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public JButton getPrev() {
    return prev;
}

public void setPrev(JButton prev) {
    this.prev = prev;
}

public JLabel getLabel() {
    return label;
}


private int getCurrent() {
    return current;
}

public void setCurrent(int current) {
    this.current = current;
}

private JLabel setLabel(CDinventoryItem cDinventoryItem) {
    return label;
}

private int Current() {
    return current;

}}
```

Comment: What is this dialog for?

Comment: The dialog displays a string, int, int, double from the array initem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example that leaves out all the extraneous details.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class RecordViewer extends JDialog {

 String items[] = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
 JButton next, prev;
 JLabel label;
 int current;

public RecordViewer(){
    super();
    current = 0;
    label = new JLabel(items[current]);
    next = new JButton("Next");
    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(current == items.length - 1){
                current = 0;
            }else{
                current++;
            }
            label.setText(items[current]);
        }
    });

    prev = new JButton("Previous");
    prev.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(current == 0){
                current = items.length - 1;
            }else{
                current--;
            }
            label.setText(items[current]);
        }
    });

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(label);
    add(next);
    add(prev);
    pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

To view this dialog you can call:

```
  new RecordViewer();
```

This example uses a simple String array and simply cycles through the array using two buttons and a simple layout. You can modify it to display your array and use a more advanced layout to make it look better.

---

UPDATE:

You can try this:

```
 public class RecordViewer extends JDialog {

  JButton next, prev;
  JLabel label;
  int current;
  CDinventoryItem [] items;

  public RecordViewer(CDinventoryItem [] array)
  {
    super(); 
    current = 0; 
    items = array;
    ....
```

And see if that helps.

Comment: Although this is probably a simple explanation.  Trying to incorporate it into what I have done makes it difficult for me.

Comment: Interesting enough I do a search for my problem, and what do I get?  My post here keeps coming up.  So apparently this problem hasn't been dealt with much...

Comment: Your sample has helped a lot.  I have sort of got it to work.  Just a few things I could use some help with.  When the JDialog window pops up it is on a blank dialog.  I have to press next or previous for it to display my toString.  I will post above.

Comment: Also when I press Next button, I receive an error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3  Only get it when it returns to the top of the array.

Comment: The previous button works fine, scrolls through the array nicely.  I have tried to alter the Next button if statement with no luck.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing what you posted as an update this morning.  Problem is the subclass    public RecordViewer(CDinventoryItem [] array)
    can't see the JLable variable declared in the superclass

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is going to display the pane once per item in the array and that is not what you want.

It sounds like you are trying to get a selected value. In that case use a inputDialog instead of message Dialog and pass the entire array.

Here is an example from the API:

```
Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
"Choose one", "Input",
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);
```

Comment: No I simply want it to display the first element in the array, and then use a next button to list the next item in the array.  The data is already inputted from the array creation.

Comment: Where is your Next button?  Sounds like you should be creating your own JDialog instead of using JOptionPane.

Comment: Um yeah,  I just spent 7 hours straight going over different reference material trying to do just that.  All were overly verbose examples of things that were far more complex than just creating a next button to display the next record.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a JDialog with a JSpinner or a JList in it.